# How can I add fields to my Sprout Form plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-sproutforms

I am not sure what I have done wrong, I am working with a fresh install of [Sprout Forms](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms).

When I create a new form and then click "Add Field" in the layout designer, this is what I am seeing.

[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: You get any error messages with devMode enabled?

Comment: Damon, this is usually due to an issue with another field type plugin. Can you confirm you are on the latest version of all of your plugins and drop us a note to sprout@barrelstrengthdesign.com and share what other plugins you have installed if the issue continues.

Comment: Hi guys! Sorry for the long delay. We've narrowed it down to another plugin with a custom field type throwing JS errors. We're up to date on everything. I've responded  to Andre with what we found. Many thanks for responding to my support ticket!

Should I close this thread I guess?